# Biased coin tossing problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have the following problem:

> A (possibly biased) coin is tossed repeatedly and independently. Let $p \in (0, 1)$ denote the probability of a head, and let $T_i$ be the toss number when the $i$th head is observed where $i = 1, 2, \dots$.
>
> Show that, if $k \ge 2$, then
>
> $$P(T_1 = j \vert T_2 = k) = (k - 1)^{-1}, \ \ \ (j = 1, \dots, k - 1),$$
>
> independently of the value of $p$. Note that this conditional law is discrete uniform on the set $\{ 1, 2, \dots, k - 1 \}$.

The solution is as follows:

> First, we determine an expression for $P(T_2 = k)$.
>
> For $k \ge 2$, we have that
>
> $$\begin{align} P(T_2 = k) &= \sum_{j = 1}^{k - 1} P(T_2 = k \vert T_1 = j) P(T_1 = j) \\ &= \sum_{j = 1}^{k - 1} (q^{k - j - 1} p)(q^{j - 1} p) \\ &= (k - 1) q^{k - 2} p^2, \end{align}$$
>
> where we have used the law of total probability in the first line. Now, using Bayes' theorem, we get that, for $k \ge 2$ and $j \in \{ 1, \dots, k - 1 \}$,
>
> $$\begin{align} P(T_1 = j \vert T_2 = k) &= \dfrac{P(T_2 = k \vert T_1 = j) P(T_1 = j)}{P(T_2 = k)} \\ &= \dfrac{(q^{k - 2} p^2) (q^{j - 1} p)}{(k - 1)q^{k - 2} p^2} = ( k -1)^{-1}. \end{align}$$

I don't understand how the first line is derived using the law of total probability. Specifically, I don't understand why the summation is to $k - 1$ instead of $k$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: You want the probability that the second head is observed at toss $k$. That can only happen if the first head happened at tosse $1$, or $2$, or ... , or $k-1$, *not* at toss $k$: you cannot have both the first *and* second head at toss $k$.

Comment: $j$ is the first instance when one saw heads while $k$ is the second time. Clearly these need to be distinct. Hence $j \neq k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the probability that the second head is observed at toss $k$. That can only happen if the first head happened **before**: at tosse $1$, or $2$, or ... , or $k-1$. **Not** at toss $k$: you cannot have both the first *and* second head at toss $k$.

Hence the summation for $j$ from $1$ to $k-1$: you could write the following terms, but for $j \geq k$ we have $\Pr[ T_2 = k \mid T_1 = j] = 0$...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is $\dfrac{(q^{k - 2} p^2) (q^{j - 1} p)}{(k - 1)q^{k - 2} p^2}$ erroneous? Shouldn't it be $\dfrac{P(T_2 = k \vert T_1 = j)P(T_1 = j)}{P(T_2 = k)} = \dfrac{q^{k - 2} p^2}{(k - 1)q^{k - 2} p^2}$?

Comment: At first glance, yes, you are right, @ThePointer (unless I misunderstood the question, that's also a consequence of the geometric distribution being [memoryless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness#Discrete_memorylessness)). That seems to be just a typo, however, as their final result is correct.